# xsl:sort I need to sort nodes and also all childern

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi everyone and thanks for the help.
I have to transform the parent node and all of his children but I do not know well how XSLT does.

Once the **<NetworkAliases>** node is selected, I want its children **<NetAlias>** to be in alphabetical order (based on the *"Name"* attribute), plus, for each child of **<NetAlias>** (really **<NetAlias>** has only one child , that is **<AddressItems>**, which has several children **<Address>**) I have to do:

1. the **<Address>** nodes that contain sub-nodes **<IPV4>** are before the nodes that have sub-nodes **<IPV6>**;
2. the **<Address>** nodes are sorted in ascending order based on the *"AddrStart"* attribute for the **<IPV4>** and the *"AddrBase"* attribute for the **<IPV6>**.

I have this XML code:

```
<NetworkAliases>
  <NetAlias UID="{02A4738B-605C-4641-9705-E83ADFDAB221}" ZoneType="1" Name="comodo">
    <AddressItems>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="114.255.52.160" AddrEnd="114.255.52.175"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="123.124.255.96" AddrEnd="123.124.255.111"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="69.195.46.36" AddrEnd="255.255.6.39"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="97.107.169.84" AddrEnd="97.107.169.87"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="97.107.175.140" AddrEnd="97.107.175.143"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="199.66.200.0" AddrEnd="199.66.207.255"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="208.49.40.28" AddrEnd="208.49.40.31"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2607F7A80E0A00000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2607F7A8100900000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
    </AddressItems>
  </NetAlias>
  <NetAlias UID="{0B9F7F4D-E23B-4D09-88F8-0CA378319316}" ZoneType="1" Name="akamai">
    <AddressItems>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="2.22.80.0" AddrEnd="2.22.95.255"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2A0226F000DF00000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="95.100.224.0" AddrEnd="95.100.239.255"/>
      </Address>
    </AddressItems>
  </NetAlias>
</NetworkAliases>
```

and this xsl (that works for the other nodes but for this part doesnt):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="PolicyItems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PolicyItem">
                <xsl:sort select="@Filename" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Predefined">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PredefinedItem">
                <xsl:sort select="@Name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NetworkAliases">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="NetAlias">
                <xsl:sort select="@Name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AddressItems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Address">
                <xsl:sort select="@Type" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PortAliases">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PortAlias">
                <xsl:sort select="@Name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- To Sort also the ports -->


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the results should be:

```
<NetworkAliases>
  <NetAlias UID="{0B9F7F4D-E23B-4D09-88F8-0CA378319316}" ZoneType="1" Name="akamai">
    <AddressItems>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="2.22.80.0" AddrEnd="2.22.95.255"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="95.100.224.0" AddrEnd="95.100.239.255"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2A0226F000DF00000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
    </AddressItems>
  </NetAlias>
  <NetAlias UID="{02A4738B-605C-4641-9705-E83ADFDAB221}" ZoneType="1" Name="comodo">
    <AddressItems>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="69.195.46.36" AddrEnd="255.255.6.39"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="97.107.169.84" AddrEnd="97.107.169.87"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="97.107.175.140" AddrEnd="97.107.175.143"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="114.255.52.160" AddrEnd="114.255.52.175"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="123.124.255.96" AddrEnd="123.124.255.111"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="199.66.200.0" AddrEnd="199.66.207.255"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="1">
        <IPV4 AddrType="2" AddrStart="208.49.40.28" AddrEnd="208.49.40.31"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2607F7A80E0A00000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
      <Address Source="2" Type="2">
        <IPV6 AddrType="4" AddrMask="48" AddrBase="2607F7A8100900000000000000000000"/>
      </Address>
    </AddressItems>
  </NetAlias>
</NetworkAliases>
```

I tryed so many times without results that finally I have to ask you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider multiple `<xsl:sort>` inside an `<xsl:for-each>` and then migrate the attributes of parent *Address* node. Also, use `substring-before` to retrieve the digits before first period in IP addresses which appears to be your sorting criteria (not the full length of digits).

Do note: below leaves out the templates not in your current XML: *PolicyItems*, *Predefined*, *PortAliases*.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NetworkAliases">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="NetAlias">
                <xsl:sort select="@Name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AddressItems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Address/*">
                <xsl:sort select="@AddrType" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>                
                <xsl:sort select="format-number(substring-before(@AddrStart, '.'), '#')" 
                          order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="AddrBase" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>

                <Address>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Address/@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </Address> 

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT 1.0 Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKu/1)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can use XSLT-2.0, because the version tag of your `xsl:stylesheet` indicates so.

You can achieve your objective by using an XSLT-2.0 sorting function (here: `sort:IPV4sorting`) which has its own namespace (here: `xmlns:sort="http://www.sort.ns"`).

Putting this together you'll get the following (partial) stylesheet. You only have to replace your `AddressItems` template and add the `xsl:function`. The rest of your code can stay the same.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sort="http://www.sort.ns">
...
    <xsl:function name="sort:IPV4sorting" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="ipv4" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="numKey">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$ipv4" regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(xs:integer(regex-group(1)),'000'),format-number(xs:integer(regex-group(2)),'000'),format-number(xs:integer(regex-group(3)),'000'),format-number(xs:integer(regex-group(4)),'000'))" />
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>   
        <xsl:value-of select="$numKey" />
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="AddressItems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Address[IPV4]">
                <xsl:sort select="sort:IPV4sorting(IPV4/@AddrStart)" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Address[IPV6]">
                <xsl:sort select="@AddrBase" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
...
```

This code creates a 12 digit *key value* (4*3=12) with `xsl:analyze-string` from the IPv4 address which is used as a sorting key in the sorting function. It does call `xsl:apply-templates` twice to handle IPv6 addresses differently from IPv4 addresses.